# Using MessageBox when part of an await has ConfigureAwait false

Tags: c#, async-await

Reading Stephen Cleary take on [not blocking on Async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) I write something like this

```
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);  
      return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
   }
}

public async void Button1_Click(...)
{
    var json = await GetJsonAsync(...);
    textBox1.Text=json;
}
```

so far so good, I understand that after the `ConfigureAwait` the method is going to continue running on a different context after `GetStringAsync` returns. 
but what about if I want to use something like `MessageBox` (which is UI) like this

```
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
   if(someValue<MAXVALUE)
   {
      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
         //var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);  //starts the REST request
         var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);    
         return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("The parameter someValue is too big!");
   }
}
```

can I do this?

Even more complicated, how about this?

```
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
   if(someValue<MAXVALUE)
   {
      try{
         using (var client = new HttpClient())
         {
            //var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);  //starts the REST request
            var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);    
            return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
         }
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("An Exception was raised!");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("The parameter someValue is too big!");
   }
}
```

Can I do this?

Now, I am thinking perhaps all the message boxes should be called outside GetJsonAync as good design, but my question is can the above thing be done?

Comment: I suppose that *after* I do the first await with configureawait false then no Messagebox is allowed, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I do this? [use a MessageBox]

Yes, but mainly because it has nothing to do with async/await or threading.
`MessageBox.Show()` is special, it is a static method and is documented as thread-safe.

You can show a MessageBox from any thread, any time.

So maybe it was the wrong example, but you do have MessageBox in the title.

```
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
   try{
     ...  // old context
     ... await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
     ...  // new context
   }
   catch
   {
      // this might bomb
      someLabel.Text = "An Exception was raised!";
   }
}
```

In this example, there could be code paths where the catch runs on the old and other paths where it runs on the new context.

Bottom line is: you don't know and should assume the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a Message Box, as it is very limited, and dated.
Also, Pop up's are annoying.
Use your own user control which enables user interaction the way you intend it.

In the context of Winforms / WPF / (and I guess UWP), only a single thread can manipulate the UI. Other threads can issue work to it via a queue of actions which eventually get invoked.

This architecture prevents other threads from constantly poking at the UI, which can make UX very janky (and thread unsafe).

The only way to communicate with it the UI work queue (in Winforms) is via the System.Windows.Form.Controls.BeginInvoke instance method, found on every form and control.

In your case:

```
public async void Button1_Click(...)
{
    var json = await GetJsonAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false);
    BeginInvoke(UpdateTextBox, json);
}

private void UpdateTextBox(string value)
{
  textBox1.Text=json;
}
```